# Discord bot cannot connect a voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot first time, but the bot can't connect to the voice channel without any error, please help me, thanks.
This command worked successfully but the bot cannot connect my voice channel  when enter 'else' statement.

Please help me.Thanks a lot.

`

```
class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if not ctx.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
        else:
            print('join')
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()
```

`

I tried to give my bot administrator in my server, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Adding the specific error you encountered would greatly increase your chances of receiving a reply.

Comment: Sorry but there is no error message when I input 'join' command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple all u need to do is to download PyNaCl,

```
pip install PyNaCl
```

[here is the error that u got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR7g3.png)